# Include scheduling in web-application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I wanted to run scheduling process in asp.net periodically in web application.

In brief,My database table is having date & deadline Hrs.I want to calculate expected dateTime from both then another table get updated (inserts 1000s of records) periodically & also want to run process of mail sending according to that calculation for the same.

This is expected scheduled process which should be executed periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Window Service* to work in backgroud or scheduling , please see below links:

[Using Timers in a Windows Service](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c6919)

Answer (score 2):

The [Quartz.NET job scheduler library](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is excellent for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this old article from [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood):
[Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

Basically he suggests that you use the cache expiration mechanism to schedule a timed task. The problem is: your web application needs to be running. What if the website isn't called at all? Well, since IIS 7.5 there is the possibility to keep your web app running at all times: [auto starting web apps](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx). Jeff suggests in the comments that his approach served well until they outgrew it. His conclusion is that for small sites this is a good approach.

Comment: @Michel Overeem: I want the suggestion, which is more efficient & easy way to do this?

Comment: @MayP I've added some more stuff. How about up-voting some of the answers that are given? If none is okay, then please expand your question to explain more what you are looking for.

Comment: @MayP so now you have a couple of answers. How about reacting on them? up-voting or explaining what you are missing. Seems that you do not put a whole lot of effort in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
   public class Email {
        private static System.Threading.Timer threadingTimer;

        public static void StartTimer()
        {
            if (threadingTimer == null)
                threadingTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Callback), HttpContext.Current, 0, 20000);
        }

        private static void Callback(object sender)
        {
            if (/* Your condition to send emails */)
                using (var context = new MyEntities())
                {
                        var users = from user in context.Usere
                                     select user;
                        foreach (var user in users)
                        {
                            // Send an email to user
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

And you have to add this to Application_Start:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         EMail.StartTimer();
    }
```

Comment: if application doesn't open for two days then?

Comment: @MayP: If you have enough permission you could set application pool timeout to 0. But if not (like me) you can put an empty webpage in your site and set another timer to read it periodically, say every 19 minutes.